# No handlers found for the logger "deluge"

Tags: python, logging, cron

I have a python script for a cronjob that deletes torrents that are older than 3 days. This script works if i run it from the terminal, however crontab gives me this error `No handlers could be found for logger "deluge"`. Can anyone please tell me how to resolve this problem?

This is the python script:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

    from deluge.log import LOG as log
    from deluge.ui.client import client
    import deluge.component as component
    from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
    import time

    ############
    cliconnect = client.connect(host='127.0.0.1',port=58846)
    seeddir = "/home/mou/CPDownloads" # Directory to ignore for torrents to remain seeding
    timedifference = 3 # Remove torrents older than this this time (in days)
    is_interactive = False # Set this to True to allow direct output or set to False for cron
    do_remove_data = True # Set to True to delete torrent data as well, false to leave it
    ###############

    oldcount = 0
    skipcount = 0
    seedcount = 0
    errorcount = 0
    torrent_ids = []

    def printSuccess(dresult, is_success, smsg):
        global is_interactive
        if is_interactive:
            if is_success:
                print "[+]", smsg
            else:
                print "[i]", smsg

    def printError(emsg):
        global is_interactive
        if is_interactive:
            print "[e]", emsg

    def endSession(esresult):
        if esresult:
            print esresult
            reactor.stop()
        else:
            client.disconnect()
            printSuccess(None, False, "Client disconnected.")
            reactor.stop()

    def printReport(rresult):
        if errorcount > 0:
            printError(None, "Failed! Number of errors: %i" % (errorcount))
        else:
            if oldcount > 0:
                printSuccess(None, True, "Removed %i torrents -- Skipped %i torrents -- Seeding %i torrents" % (oldcount, skipcount, seedcount))
            else:
                printSuccess(None, True, "No old torrents! -- Skipped %i torrents -- Seeding %i torrents" % (skipcount, seedcount))
        endSession(None)

    def on_torrents_status(torrents):
        global filtertime
        tlist=[]
        for torrent_id, status in torrents.items():
            if status["save_path"] == seeddir:
                global seedcount
                seedcount += 1
            else:
                unixtime = "%s" % (status["time_added"])
                numunixtime = int(unixtime[:-2])
                humantime = time.ctime(numunixtime)
                if numunixtime < filtertime:
                    global do_remove_data
                    global oldcount
                    oldcount += 1
                    successmsg = " Removed %s:  %s from %s" % (humantime, status["name"], status["save_path"])
            errormsg = "Error removing %s" % (status["name"])
            tlist.append(client.core.remove_torrent(torrent_id, do_remove_data).addCallbacks(printSuccess, printError, callbackArgs = (True, successmsg), errbackArgs = (errormsg)))
                else:
                    global skipcount
                    skipcount += 1
                    printSuccess(None, False, " Skipping %s: %s from %s" % (humantime, status["name"], status["save_path"]))
        defer.DeferredList(tlist).addCallback(printReport)

    def on_session_state(result):
        client.core.get_torrents_status({"id": result}, ["name","time_added","save_path",]).addCallback(on_torrents_status)

    def on_connect_success(result):
        printSuccess(None, True, "Connection was successful!")
        global timedifference
        global filtertime
        curtime = time.time()
        filtertime = curtime - (timedifference * 24 * 60 * 60)
        printSuccess(None, False, "Current unix time is %i" % (curtime))
        printSuccess(None, False, "Filtering torrents older than %s" % (time.ctime(int(filtertime))))
        client.core.get_session_state().addCallback(on_session_state)

    cliconnect.addCallbacks(on_connect_success, endSession, errbackArgs=("Connection failed: check settings and try again."))

    reactor.run()
```

This is the output when I run it from the terminal:

```
    mou@mou-lanister:~/scripts$ ./cpmanagertest.py 
    [+] Connection was successful!
    [i] Current unix time is 1404169193
    [i] Filtering torrents older than Sun Jun 29 18:59:53 2014
    [i]  Skipping Mon Jun 30 03:57:52 2014: War.Horse.2011.1080p.MKV.x264.AC3.DTS.NL.Subs from /home/mou/CPDownloads/
    [i]  Skipping Mon Jun 30 04:00:00 2014: The Legend Of Hercules 2014 1080p BluRay DTS x264 PublicHD from /home/mou/CPDownloads/
    [+]  Removed Sun Jun 29 16:52:16 2014:  Paranormal.Activity.The.Marked.Ones.2014.EXTENDED.1080p.BluRay.x264-SPARKS [PublicHD] from /home/mou/CPDownloads/
    [+]  Removed Sun Jun 29 17:07:12 2014:  The.Hobbit.The.Desolation.Of.Smaug.2013.1080p.BluRay.DTS.x264-PublicHD from /home/mou/CPDownloads/
    [+]  Removed Sun Jun 29 17:22:08 2014:  thor the dark world 2013 1080p bluray x264 sparks publichd from /home/mou/CPDownloads/
    [+]  Removed Sun Jun 29 16:24:32 2014:  The.Conjuring.2013.1080p.BluRay.x264-ALLiANCE [PublicHD] from /home/mou/CPDownloads/
    [+]  Removed Sun Jun 29 17:00:48 2014:  Her.2013.1080p.BluRay.x264-SPARKS [PublicHD] from /home/mou/CPDownloads/
    [+]  Removed Sun Jun 29 17:20:00 2014:  Rush 2013 1080p 60fps BluRay x264-zologne from /home/mou/CPDownloads/
    [+]  Removed Sun Jun 29 17:22:08 2014:  Escape.Plan.2013.1080p.BluRay.DTS-HD.MA.7.1.x264-PublicHD from /home/mou/CPDownloads/
    [+]  Removed Sun Jun 29 17:05:04 2014:  The.Fifth.Estate.2013.1080p.BluRay.x264-SPARKS [PublicHD] from /home/mou/CPDownloads/
    [+] Removed 8 torrents -- Skipped 2 torrents -- Seeding 0 torrents
    [i] Client disconnected.
```

This is the log for crontab job:

No handlers could be found for logger "deluge"
No handlers could be found for logger "deluge"
No handlers could be found for logger "deluge"
No handlers could be found for logger "deluge"
No handlers could be found for logger "deluge"
No handlers could be found for logger "deluge"
No handlers could be found for logger "deluge"
No handlers could be found for logger "deluge"
No handlers could be found for logger "deluge"
No handlers could be found for logger "deluge"
No handlers could be found for logger "deluge"
No handlers could be found for logger "deluge"

After I added the debugging code I got the following error:

```
DEBUG:deluge:ConfigManager started..
INFO:deluge:Connecting to daemon at 127.0.0.1:58846..
INFO:deluge:Connected to daemon at 127.0.0.1:58846..
ERROR:deluge:RPCError Message Received!
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RPCRequest: daemon.login(localclient, f4f86361c7b9443464d0078f8d7c012e2ed63ce9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deluge/core/rpcserver.py", line 259, in dispatch
    ret = component.get("AuthManager").authorize(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deluge/core/authmanager.py", line 93, in authorize
    raise BadLoginError("Password does not match")

BadLoginError: Password does not match
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG:deluge:_on_login_fail(): [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'deluge.ui.client.DelugeRPCError'>: <deluge.ui.client.DelugeRPCError object at 0x7f58263f6150>
]
DEBUG:deluge:on_connect_fail: [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'deluge.ui.client.DelugeRPCError'>: <deluge.ui.client.DelugeRPCError object at 0x7f58263f6150>
]
INFO:deluge:Connection lost to daemon at 127.0.0.1:58846 reason: Connection was closed cleanly.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ah, it's one of the [warts of Python](https://code.google.com/p/rainforce/wiki/WartsOfPython#Logging_hidden_magic_%282.x_tested,_3.x_unknown%29).

Add this to suppress the messages:

```
import logging 
logging.getLogger('deluge').addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
```

Or write everything to stderr:

```
import logging, sys
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr, level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: That did solve the problem. No more errors, but now I have over 30 "cron" processes running and the log file shows no output.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, err, @user3787700. I've added another stanza that will write errors to stderr vs tossing them, to help with debugging.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Appreciate your effort!

Comment: I have edited my question with the badpassword error, please have a look.